How to change the color of the bottom plot of my 3D plot?
I wanted to make this 3D plot over this 0 plot to better see the difference, but the problem is that they share the same blue color. I was thinking of making the 0 one red, for a better contrast, but I don't know how. This is the code that I use for the plot and lower I will add a photo of the 3D plot that I got. I know I could just make a different plot instead of 0 data, but I am still going through different parameters and I don't want to have to switch more things when I want to try something different.
data61 = 
  ParallelTable[
   Re[d[1, 1, t, 1, 0, 0, 0.2, 0.4, T]] // Re, {T, 0.1, 6, 0.1}, {t, 
    0, 4, 0.1}];
p0 = 0 data61;
p4 = ListPlot3D[{p0, data61}, DataRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 6}}, 
   PlotRange -> All, PlotTheme -> "Scientific", 
   ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
   AxesLabel -> {t, T, Subscript[\[ScriptCapitalD], 2]}];



Use two different ListPlot3Ds (one for your function and one for the 0 plane), and join them with Show.

Since d wasn't defined in your question I use Plus
d = Plus;

data61 = 
  ParallelTable[Re[d[1, 1, t, 1, 0, 0, 0.2, 0.4, T]], {T, 0.1, 6, 0.1}, {t, 0, 4, 0.1}];

pa =
 ListPlot3D[data61,
 DataRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 6}},
 PlotRange -> All,
 PlotTheme -> "Scientific",
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap",
 PlotLegends -> Automatic,
 AxesLabel -> {t, T, Subscript[\[ScriptCapitalD], 2]}];

pb =
  ListPlot3D[0 data61, 
  PlotStyle -> Red,
  DataRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 6}},
  PlotRange -> All];

Show[pa, pb]


